# Transactions - The MSDTC transaction manager's WS-AtomicTransaction protocol service 'Version10' is disabled

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, transactions, msdtc

I have a WCF service that is consumed by client workstations.
Now, one of the clients running on Windows 8, is throwing the following exception:

**The transaction flowed Could Not Be unmarshaled. The Following exception occurred: The MSDTC transaction manager's WS-AtomicTransaction protocol service 'Version10' is disabled and can not unmarshal incoming transactions.**

The settings on distributed transactions have been carried out in the source code and the workstations.

I tried to enable the protocol as described in this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347734(v=vs.100).aspx

But I am not working with certificates (authentication is not required) and could not apply the changes.

In the other workstations it is working perfectly.

Comment: What were they running before windows 8?

Comment: It's running in Windows XP , Seven and 8.

Comment: I discovered that customer windows 8 version is the single edition. I am looking on google some documentation about support for distributed transactions that operating system, but not yet found. I believe this is the cause ...

Comment: This error can be for error in the certificates installed between both central and slaves machines. It is important, to review the if proper certificated are in place.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that really the version of windows, as I had commented.
The Single Edition version of Windows 8 does not support distributed transactions.
When I replace to the Professional version, the system worked perfectly.